Prove $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x^2}=1$
Prove $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x^2}=1$
ROUGH WORK
so to start I know
$|x-1|<\delta$
so that gives me
$$\frac{1}{1-\delta}>\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{1+\delta}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{(1-\delta)^2} > \frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{(1+\delta)^2}$$
I also know that $$\frac{|x^2-1|}{x^2}<\varepsilon$$
or
$$|x-1|\frac{(|x-1|+|2|)}{x^2}<\varepsilon$$
or
$$\frac{\delta(\delta+2)}{(1-\delta)^2}<\varepsilon$$
let $\delta < \frac{1}{2}$
so
$$10\delta<\varepsilon$$
so $\delta <\frac{\varepsilon}{10}$
END OF ROUGH WORK
PROOF
let $\delta = min(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon}{10})$
we then have
$$|x-1|<\delta$$
$$(1-\delta)^2<|x|^2<(1+\delta)^2$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-\delta)^2}-1 > \frac{1}{x^2}-1>\frac{1}{(1+\delta)^2}-1$$
not sure of how to proceed from here

"let $\delta > \frac{1}{2}$" and "let $\delta = max(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3\varepsilon}{10})$" are fatal errors. When you are given a small $\varepsilon$, you need to choose your $\delta$ accordingly small (i.e. near to $0$).

Oops, i wasn't thinking properly, let's say it's delta <1/2 and min instead, then what would I do

Where does your $\frac{10}3$ come from? I find $10$ instead.

Substituting delta =1/2 in all but one places

Oops, looks like I made a calculation mistake. I am outside right now, will correct it when I get back .

Let $\delta=\min(1/2,\varepsilon/10)$ (from our previous comments). If $|x-1|<\delta$ then (from your own "rough work") $$\frac{|x^2-1|}{x^2}<\frac{\delta(\delta+2)}{(1-\delta)^2}\le10\delta\le\varepsilon.$$

instead start at "$|x-1|<\delta$", i believe that $|x^{-2}-1|<\varepsilon$ is more useful.

@Kempa The OP's approach proved fruitful (see previous comment).

We can start like this
$$ \left\lvert \frac{1-x^2}{x^2}\right\rvert = \frac{|x-1||x+1|}{x^2}. $$
Notice we have the $|x-1|$ term present, which we can make arbitrarily small. Now the question is, if we restrict $x$ somewhere close to $1$, how large can the remaining quantity get?
$$ x\in \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \frac{|x+1|}{x^2} \leqslant \frac{5}{2} \cdot 4 = 10. $$
Hence
$$ x\in \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \frac{|x-1||x+1|}{x^2} \leqslant 10|x-1| \overset{?}< \varepsilon $$
Thus, we can see it is sufficient to take $\delta \leqslant \min \left\lbrace \frac{1}{2},\frac{\varepsilon}{10}\right\rbrace$.

We don't have to restrict $x$ to within $1/2$ distance from $1$. We can restrict it much closer, if we chose to. The point here is to not let $x^2$ get close to $0$.
